# Migration management .NET 5

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5

I state that I am a student and I have just created a management software, I used the "code first" approach to create the database, I realized that I have eliminated some migrations, what can I do to solve the problem? Can it cause me problems in what way?

Thanks for your help

I tried to create new migrations but without success

Comment: Migrations? What does it mean in the context of your software. For "code first" you need some sort of framework that knows that approach. You might need to add a tag here. For getting help you need to get way more explicit here. What have you tried. What is happening. What did you expect instead. What errors do you get. All those details will help understand your problem so we are able to help. Without we can do almost nothing.

Comment: Migration requires a connection to the database.  I've helped a few people recently that connection to database was failing so migration never completed.  I think it is really a deficiency in the Microsoft Migration to properly handle connections to the database after changing version of Net/Core.